PrimeFaces Jakarta 14.0.4 dataExporter does not export PDF
<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:exportIcons/pdfExport.png']}" width="40"/>
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="datalist" fileName="Companies"/>
</h:commandLink>

Produces error message: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: com/lowagie/text/Phrase
I tried using openpdf-1.3.30.jar and itextpdf-5.5.13.4.jar and both produced the above error message.
Which PDF JAR file should I use?

I found out that openpdf-2.0.3.jar works very nicely.

Yes PrimeFaces uses OpenLibre not iText anymore versions for 14.0.0 are listed here: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/14_0_0/#/gettingstarted/dependencies It looks like OpenPDF 1.4.1 or higher.

PrimeFaces uses OpenLibre not iText anymore versions for 14.0.0 are listed here: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/14_0_0/#/gettingstarted/dependencies It looks like OpenPDF 1.4.1 or higher.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>

